# WCF Data Services Untyped provider LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql, wcf-data-services

Hi I'm working on an untyped provider for WCF Data Services. Is there a tutorial on how can I implement a LINQ to SQL?

Comment: There would have been thousands of links if you have typed this on google!

Comment: @Sajeetharan yep there are thousand of links but none of it is the one i need. I'm specifically pointing on integrating linq to sql on wcf data services on an untyped provider.

Answer (score 0):

Check these links

-Create a Data Service Using a LINQ to SQL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373841(v=vs.110).aspx

-WCF Data Services http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668794(v=vs.110).aspx

-Biginners Guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee720180

-wcf data services untyped provider link  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/03/02/creating-a-data-service-provider-part-9-un-typed.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links but I already have read those prior to these post. What I really want is a wcf data services implementing untyped provider that is using LINQ to SQL. I'm really lost incorporating those two items because the last link that you have sent me is only using LINQ to Objects.